# Powershell argument validation issues

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments

I'm calling a powershell script like so, from within another script.

```
function test_execute_sql_2_direct_query()
  {
    & C:\Server\Scripts\PowerShellDeploy\Execute-SQL-Command.ps1 -SERVER_NAME "myserver" -SQL_COMMAND_TYPE "input" -SQL_FILE ".\select.sql" -USER_NAME "username" -PASSWORD "password" -DATABASE "accounts"
  }
```

When I call that function I get an error message from Powershell that says 'Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Query'.  The argument is null or empty....'

I don't quite follow why I'm getting that message?  The Execute-SQL-Command script doesn't have an argument called 'Query'.  Quite possible I'm missing something.

Here's its paramenter section:

```
param(
[Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Server Name")]
[string]$SERVER_NAME = "",

[Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Database")]
[string]$DATABASE = "",

    [Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Path to .SQL File to run. Used in input file mode (not direct query mode)")]
[string]$SQL_FILE ="",  

    [Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Server Port (default = 1433)")]
[string]$SERVER_PORT = "1433",

    [Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Server Transport (default = tcp")]
[string]$TRANSPORT = "tcp", 

[Parameter(
         HelpMessage="Method of connecting to database <passthrough, credentialed>")]
[string]$CONNECT_METHOD = "passthrough",

[Parameter(
        HelpMessage="Username -- used only for credentialed login")]
[string]$USER_NAME = "username",

[Parameter(
        HelpMessage="Command type-- direct query or input file (.sql)")]
[string]$SQL_COMMAND_TYPE = "DIRECT_QUERY",

[Parameter(
        HelpMessage="SQL statement text type-- used in direct queries")]
[string]$SQL_STATEMENT = "",

[Parameter(
        HelpMessage="Password -- used only for credentialed login")]
[string]$PASSWORD = "pwd")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is chalked up to user error-- the actual error was coming from within a line called in Execute-SQL-Command.ps1-- specifically, the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet.